# Qt5 signal capture to slot generates runtime error "signal does not exist"

Tags: qt5, signals-slots

I have a program in Qt5 which simply creates and runs my class (I *think* it has to be a class to take advantage of the signal/slot mechanism but I'm not sure that's relevant for my specific problem):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MyApp myApp;
    return myApp.run(argc, argv);
}
```

In the class itself, I instantiate a `QGuiApplication`, then try to capture its state-change signal:

```
class MyApp : public QObject {
public:
    MyApp() { }
    ~MyApp() { }
    int run(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
        connect(
            app,  SIGNAL(applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState)),
            this, SLOT(stateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState)));

        // blah blah blah

        return app.exec();
    }
public slots:
    void stateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState newState) {
        std::cout << "State changed to " << newState << '\n';
    }
};
```

Now, from what I understand, this should connect the signal from the `QGuiApplication` object through to the slot function in the `MyApp` object. But I'm obviously doing something wrong since it's complaining at run time that the signal does not exist:

```
QObject::connect:
    No such signal QObject::applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState)
        in Prog.cpp:16
```

The `Qobject::` in the signal name is a bit of a worry. I would have thought it would be `QGuiApplication` but, since I'm new at this Qt stuff, I'm unsure if this is a problem.

What is the correct way to connect that signal so that a change in the application state would result in `stateChanged` being called?

Comment: It's not exactly supported to create QObjects before creating a QCoreApplication, by the way. Why do you have this strange encapsulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For signals to work, one need to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro at the beginning of the first private section of a `QObject`-derived class.

```
class MyApp : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    // ...
}
```

See [Qt 5.x Docs on `Q_OBJECT`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT)

Comment: That gets me a bucket load of *compile* time errors of the form `no matching function for call to ‘MyApp::connect(QGuiApplication&, const char*, MyApp*, const char*)’`. But it appears this is because `app` in on-stack rather than a pointer. So, once I pass `&app` rather than `app`, it works fine. Cheers.

Comment: You are using the MOC compiler before calling the C++ compiler, right?